# How to use AggregateResult in java code using Partner wsdl of salesforce

Tags: soap-api, java, partner-wsdl

Query: Select count(id) from Account

When i execute the above query using java code I am unable to fetch the records it gives null value whenrun through java code. From the following link https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_query_aggregateresult.htm i got to know we have to AggregateResult but it gives an error AggregateResult cannot be resolved to a type. Please help me on this as how to use AggreagteResult in java code using salesforce soap api and partner wsdl

Comment: Does `Select count(Id) from Account` work?

Comment: The queries that contain aggregate functions are not working

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SFSE! At minimum, in order to help you, we'll need to see some code and the exact error message in order to answer your question better. Please read about [ask], then [edit] your question to include the code and error. As Felix said, `select count(*) from account` isn't correct, you need to use either `select count(id) from account` or `select count() from account`.

Comment: @sfdcfox Select count(id) from account will work but could you please help me how to fetch the records for the query using java code

Comment: The records are not returned in an Aggregate Query, only the count of the records is returned. Instead, you'd use the `SELECT <field-list> FROM <sObject>` without using any aggregate functions or group by clauses. Aggregate functions only give you summary-level information about the requested data.